# Windows 7 installation breaks due to some hard disk error

Tags: windows-7, installation, chkdsk

I am trying to install Windows 7 from a bootable USB flash drive, but it breaks in between and gives me this error.

```
The file or directory c.windows.winsxs.x86_mdmmoto1.inf...is corrupt or unreadable.
Please run the chkdsk utility.
```

I tried to perform `chkdsk c: /f` as was suggested in the error message. It runs and completes 48% and gives the following error:

```
Failed to transfer logged messages to the event log with status 50.
```

Please help me to solve this problem.

Comment: I would replace the HDD.

Answer (score 1):

Sounds like you have a faulty drive, and because of that the install fails (files vanish unexpectedly and/or become corrupted), and CHKDSK quits at 48% (because it can't finish).

The error it's throwing about the event log is because you're running the CHKDSK from the recovery/install media, and so it fails to write its results to the Event Logs (since they don't exist, since your not running a full install of Windows).

Determine what make/model of drive you have, and head to the drive manufacturer's website and see if they have any specific drive testing utilities you can run to check the drive's health.